# Error populating Jlist with data from ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, object, arraylist, jlist

I'm making a program that will generate Emails for names pulled from an excel sheet. 
The issue I'm having is that when i try to transfer my Arraylist data to the Jlist ListModel, nothing shows up in the Gui.

I know posting the entire code is overkill, but id rather overshare than have people ask for additional parts in order figure out what's going on. the problem is strictly between the Main and Window classes (pretty sure).

This is the person class to create person objects

```
public class person {
    private String fName, lName, serialNum, location, isDone;
// default constructor
public person() {
    fName = "default";
    lName = "default";
    serialNum = "0";
    location = "nowhere";
    isDone = "";
}

public person(String serialNum1, String fName1, String lName1, String 
location1, String isDone1) {
    this.fName = fName1;
    this.lName = lName1;
    this.serialNum = serialNum1;
    this.location = location1;
    this.isDone = isDone1;
}

// set first name
public void setFirst(String newFirst) {
    this.fName = newFirst;
}

// get first name
public String getFirst() {
    return fName;
}

////////
// set last name
public void setLast(String newLast) {
    this.lName = newLast;
}

// get last name
public String getLast() {
    return lName;
}

/////////
// set serial number
public void setSerial(String newSerial) {
    this.serialNum = newSerial;
}

// get serial number
public String getSerial() {
    return serialNum;
}

/////////
// set location
public void setLocation(String newLocation) {
    this.location = newLocation;
}

// get location
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

// set done
public void setDone(String newDone) {
    this.isDone = newDone;
}

// get done
public String getDone() {
    return isDone;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("serial: " + serialNum + " |  Name: " + fName + " " + lName + " |  Location: " + location + " |  Completed: "+isDone+ "\n");
}
public String label() {
    return " Name:                    " + fName + " " + lName + "                 done: "+isDone+ "\n";
}


///////////
// script///
///////////
public String printScript() {
    return "Hello " + fName + " " + lName + "\n\n" +

            "script"+

            "Serial #: " + serialNum + "\n\n" +

            "Location: " + location + "\n\n" +

            ;
}
}
```

Main class reads the excel file and pulls the names/data from it. It then puts that data into Arr a.
'a' successfully stores the objects in the arraylist, but when trying to move the contents of 'a' over to the GUI using 'w.fill(a);' it doesnt do anything. the gui shows up with a blank jList.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
// connect program to desired excel file
private static final String fileName = "C:\\bigList.xlsx";
public static Arr a = new Arr();
public static Window w = new Window();

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    String subject = "title";
    String body = "See%20it";

    // temporary variables to store excel data for 1 row.
    // probably some way to make it more efficient than using nextCell. go by column
    // # or something
    String serial = "";
    String first = "";
    String last = "";
    String location = "";
    // could be changed to boolean
    String done = "";
    int jump;
    // create arraylist to store excel file

    try {

        // initialize reading of excel file
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

        // opens workbook for java to read
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

        // gets workbook sheet, usually 0, can be other values in case of 
multiple
        // sheets
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // initialize iterator for new rows
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

        // while there is a row with data it will keep going
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            // increment var reset. stores iterator position
            jump = 0;

            // adds temp data to arraylist
            a.getList().add(new person(serial, first, last, location,done));

            // since only some columns of 'completed' are populated, the 'done' variable has
            // to be reset to null
            // otherwise the status will remain as yes, after the first yes, since that is
            // the only other variable state
            done = "";

            // initialize row iterator
            Row currentRow = iterator.next();

            // initialize cell iterator
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

            // while there is data in a cell, it will keep iterating to the right to the
            // next cell
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                // increments column/cell value
                jump++;

                // create cell object
                Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

                // if cell contains string & isnt null value, will jump to subgroup of if
                // statements
                if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING && 
currentCell.getCellType() != null) {

                    // depending on position, store in corresponding temp value
                    // probably a better way to do this
                    // System.out.println(jump);

                    if (jump == 1) {
                        serial = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    if (jump == 2) {
                        first = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    if (jump == 3) {
                        last = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    if (jump == 4) {
                        location = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    if (jump == 5) {
                        done = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    // no numeric values so nothing needed
                }

                // if cellIncrementer encounters empty cell it breaks loop and moves down to
                // next row
                else if (currentCell.getCellType() == null) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        // removes column headers row from list
        a.getList().remove(0);
        a.getList().remove(0);

        // error catch messages
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    System.out.println(a.getList());
    // ISSUE
    // 'a' arraylist in is not getting transferred to gui
    w.fill(a);
    w.run();

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
}

// create outlook email.
// Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI(
// "mailto:prrout@inautix.co.in?subject="+subject+"&body="+body) );
```

}

window class that generates gui

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

DefaultListModel<person> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

public Window() {

    JList<person> list = new JList<person>(listModel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JButton button = new JButton("Generate Email");
    button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel lblSelectPeople = new JLabel("Select Person(s)");
    lblSelectPeople.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    lblSelectPeople.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(lblSelectPeople);
}

// needs to be variable 'a' from Main class
public void fill(Arr a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.getList().size(); i++) {
        listModel.addElement(a.getList().get(i));
    }
}

public void run() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window frame = new Window();

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.getContentPane().setSize(800, 400);
                frame.setBounds(200, 50, 630, 500);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}}

my arraylist class

public class Arr {
// create arraylist instance
ArrayList<person> arr = new ArrayList<person>();

// create getter unnecessary
public Arr() {
}

public ArrayList<person> getList() {
    return this.arr;
}}
```

Comment: You're asking a problem that concerns a bug that occurs when several large and complex classes interact, something difficult for you or us to solve, doubly hard for us since we don't have compilable/runnable code and you do. I would suggest that the first thing that you should do is use a debugger to isolate the problem. If still stuck and you need our help, then you need to create and post a valid [mcve], a posting of a ***small*** compilable and runnable program, one that fits here in your question, that we can compile and that demonstrates the problem directly for us.

Comment: OK, I've gone through this code, and you're creating more than one Window variable. One you fill with data, the other you display. Check your code above -- it should have `new Window()` only **once**, and you call this twice, proving what I'm saying. It's a careless mistake, but a common one.

Comment: ^thanks. i switched the 'Window frame' variable to static in the Window class and got rid of the 'Window w' in the Main class and that solved it. i appreciate the insight.

Comment: And that is not a recommended thing to do, as you lose all benefit of OOPs when doing that, and increase the risk for bugs due to increased cyclomatic complexity -- look it up.

Comment: ^i think i figured out the (correct) way to fix it. i put the Arraylist instance into a singleton class and that cleaned up a lot of the issues with accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating more than one Window variable which is easily proven if you search your code above for `new Window()`. This should appear once, and you're calling it twice. One Window you call `fill(...)` on, and give it data, the other you're creating in the `run()` method, you **don't** call `fill(...)` on and instead display it **without** data. Solution: don't do this. Create one object, fill it, and display it.

My MCVE that proves the point:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static Arr a = new Arr();
    public static Window w = new Window();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // fill the gui with dummy data for our purposes without need of
        // outside excel libraries
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String fName1 = "first name " + i;
            String lName1 = "last name " + i;
            a.getList().add(new Person(fName1, lName1));
        }
        a.getList().remove(0);
        a.getList().remove(0);
        System.out.println(a.getList());
        w.fill(a);
        w.run();
    }
}
```

```
class Window extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    DefaultListModel<Person> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

    public Window() {
        JList<Person> list = new JList<Person>(listModel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JButton button = new JButton("Generate Email");
        button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel lblSelectPeople = new JLabel("Select Person(s)");
        lblSelectPeople.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblSelectPeople.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(lblSelectPeople);
    }

    public void fill(Arr a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.getList().size(); i++) {
            listModel.addElement(a.getList().get(i));
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // ******Don't create a new Window object!!!!!!!!!!!! **********

                    // Window frame = new Window();
                    // frame.setVisible(true);
                    // frame.getContentPane().setSize(800, 400);
                    // frame.setBounds(200, 50, 630, 500);

                    Window frame = Window.this;
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.getContentPane().setSize(800, 400);
                    frame.setBounds(200, 50, 630, 500);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
class Arr {
    ArrayList<Person> arr = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public ArrayList<Person> getList() {
        return this.arr;
    }
}
```

```
// Should be named Person, not person
class Person {
    private String fName, lName;

    public Person() {
        fName = "default";
        lName = "default";
    }

    public Person(String fName1, String lName1) {
        this.fName = fName1;
        this.lName = lName1;
    }

    public void setFirst(String newFirst) {
        this.fName = newFirst;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setLast(String newLast) {
        this.lName = newLast;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return lName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (" |  Name: " + fName + " " + lName);
    }

    public String label() {
        return " Name:                    " + fName + " " + lName + "                 done: "
                + "\n";
    }

    public String printScript() {
        return "Hello " + fName + " " + lName + "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Other unrelated issues:

- Avoid setting sizes/bounds and such and instead use cleaner ways of setting sizes, including giving the JList a visible row count and calling `setPrototypeCellValue(...)` on your JList to set its width
- Rename the `person` class to `Person`. Your code should follow [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) -- variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.
- Your Arr class serves no useful purpose that can't be achieved with simply using an `ArrayList<Person>` object. Get rid of this class.
- Your Person data would be better displayed in a JTable and not a JList. Consider using a DefaultTableModel and JTable in place of your JList.
- Avoid creating classes that extend JFrame since this forces you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture to state that the window you're creating is likely not the base application window but rather a sub-window or "dialog" window. If so, you're much better off creating and displaying the data within a JDialog and not a JFrame.
- Avoid using class names that clash with core Java class names, such as "Window". Use something more specific and descriptive.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i had completely overlooked that.